# IOS Maps App Using Google SDK (ERROR)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Xcode is giving me this error. I am trying to create a maps app using the Google SDK. ANY HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M8GR.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing MapKit code with Google Maps code. Google maps doesn't call things "annotations", it calls them Markers. Please read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) to get a better understanding of what you need to do.